# apache route to program download

Tags: apache

I am looking to host a ".exe" file for our clients to download and i wanted to place it at "www.example.com/file". i have created a .htaccess route from "/file" to the location of the program but when you go there the browser doesnt know what file extension to use.

Is it possible to slip the file extension in there?

Comment: I'm 98% sure that there isn't in pure Apache htaccess

Comment: This should be on serverfault instead...

Comment: Well, I voted that too, but... gotta wait till it gets the votes.

Comment: Why don’t you just name the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use .htaccess to forward the browser to the .exe file.

```
RewriteRule /file /file.exe [R,L]
```

If you really want to keep it hidden for some reason then you'd have to write a script to output a `Content-disposition` header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mimetype, and then, it depends on the browser if it changes the extension or not. Some developers use an iframe with the file, with extenstion, to hide the ugly url.

There is a big change apache already sets the mimetype.

According to [this site](http://filext.com/file-extension/EXE), the mimetype should be one of the following:
application/octet-stream 
application/x-msdownload 
application/exe 
application/x-exe 
application/dos-exe 
vms/exe 
application/x-winexe 
application/msdos-windows 
application/x-msdos-program